# java opencv GLIBC_2.14 NOT FOUND

Tags: java, opencv, tomcat, centos, centos6

I've been trying to figure this out ALL WEEKEND.  Still no luck.

I'm using CentOS release 6.9(Final)

I tried these instructions :

```
tar xvfz glibc-2.14.tar.gz
cd glibc-2.14
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14
make
sudo make install
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib:$LD_LIBRARY
```

from here [RHEL 6 - how to install 'GLIBC_2.14' or 'GLIBC_2.15'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32316707/rhel-6-how-to-install-glibc-2-14-or-glibc-2-15)

But when I export LD_LIBRARY_PATH I get segmentation fault when type in ANY command like "cd,ls,nano"

I also followed these instructions : https://github.com/FezVrasta/ark-server-tools/wiki/Install-of-required-versions-of-glibc-and-gcc-on-RHEL-CentOS

I'm afraid I'm going break the server soon.

When I try to deploy my openCV app this is the error message I get

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ocrController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ocrManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ocrManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tess'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tess' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/demo-ocr/WEB-INF/lib/tesseract-impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/tess/Tess.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/temp/opencv_openpnp2554550189770510126/nu/pattern/opencv/linux/x86_64/libopencv_java320.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/temp/opencv_openpnp2554550189770510126/nu/pattern/opencv/linux/x86_64/libopencv_java320.so)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:135) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5456) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_141]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_141]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_141]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_141]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_141]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ocrManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tess'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tess' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/demo-ocr/WEB-INF/lib/tesseract-impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/tess/Tess.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/temp/opencv_openpnp2554550189770510126/nu/pattern/opencv/linux/x86_64/libopencv_java320.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/temp/opencv_openpnp2554550189770510126/nu/pattern/opencv/linux/x86_64/libopencv_java320.so)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tess' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/demo-ocr/WEB-INF/lib/tesseract-impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/tess/Tess.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/temp/opencv_openpnp2554550189770510126/nu/pattern/opencv/linux/x86_64/libopencv_java320.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/temp/opencv_openpnp2554550189770510126/nu/pattern/opencv/linux/x86_64/libopencv_java320.so)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1232) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1131) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/temp/opencv_openpnp2554550189770510126/nu/pattern/opencv/linux/x86_64/libopencv_java320.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/temp/opencv_openpnp2554550189770510126/nu/pattern/opencv/linux/x86_64/libopencv_java320.so)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
        at nu.pattern.OpenCV$SharedLoader.<init>(OpenCV.java:204) ~[opencv-3.2.0-1.jar:na]
        at nu.pattern.OpenCV$SharedLoader.<init>(OpenCV.java:185) ~[opencv-3.2.0-1.jar:na]
        at nu.pattern.OpenCV$SharedLoader$Holder.<clinit>(OpenCV.java:225) ~[opencv-3.2.0-1.jar:na]
        at nu.pattern.OpenCV$SharedLoader.getInstance(OpenCV.java:229) ~[opencv-3.2.0-1.jar:na]
        at nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared(OpenCV.java:179) ~[opencv-3.2.0-1.jar:na]
        at com.tess.Tess.<clinit>(Tess.java:60) ~[tesseract-impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:170) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1224) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        ... 56 common frames omitted

May 20, 2018 1:06:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/demo-ocr]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ocrController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ocrManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ocrManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tess'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tess' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/demo-ocr/WEB-INF/lib/tesseract-impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/tess/Tess.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/temp/opencv_openpnp2554550189770510126/nu/pattern/opencv/linux/x86_64/libopencv_java320.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/temp/opencv_openpnp2554550189770510126/nu/pattern/opencv/linux/x86_64/libopencv_java320.so)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:135)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5456)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ocrManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tess'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tess' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/demo-ocr/WEB-INF/lib/tesseract-impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/tess/Tess.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/temp/opencv_openpnp2554550189770510126/nu/pattern/opencv/linux/x86_64/libopencv_java320.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/temp/opencv_openpnp2554550189770510126/nu/pattern/opencv/linux/x86_64/libopencv_java320.so)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tess' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/demo-ocr/WEB-INF/lib/tesseract-impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/tess/Tess.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/temp/opencv_openpnp2554550189770510126/nu/pattern/opencv/linux/x86_64/libopencv_java320.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/temp/opencv_openpnp2554550189770510126/nu/pattern/opencv/linux/x86_64/libopencv_java320.so)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1232)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1131)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
        ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/temp/opencv_openpnp2554550189770510126/nu/pattern/opencv/linux/x86_64/libopencv_java320.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/temp/opencv_openpnp2554550189770510126/nu/pattern/opencv/linux/x86_64/libopencv_java320.so)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at nu.pattern.OpenCV$SharedLoader.<init>(OpenCV.java:204)
        at nu.pattern.OpenCV$SharedLoader.<init>(OpenCV.java:185)
        at nu.pattern.OpenCV$SharedLoader$Holder.<clinit>(OpenCV.java:225)
        at nu.pattern.OpenCV$SharedLoader.getInstance(OpenCV.java:229)
        at nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared(OpenCV.java:179)
        at com.tess.Tess.<clinit>(Tess.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:170)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1224)
        ... 56 more

May 20, 2018 1:06:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/demo-ocr.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/demo-ocr]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Oh and when I type in /lib/libc.so.6 version 2.12 comes up. but ldd --version gives me 2.16

Comment: There were questions posted already on how to upgrade GLIBC. If you don't know what you're doing, you'll get serious problems.

Comment: Yeah this whole process is making me sweat buckets.  Which is why I need some help

Comment: @joejoeso, you have installed the extra glibc to a "hidden location", which is OK. But the command `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib:$LD_LIBRARY` can only be used for running the application that requires glibc-2.14. ... All other commands: Use another terminal session. And do not add the new "path" to e.g. bashrc !