# Installed glib isn't being listed under installed packages

Tags: linux, redhat, glibc, yum

I currently have glibc 2.12 installed on RHEL 6.3. I needed to install glib 2.14 for a different install. It appears to of installed, but when I do "yum list glibc", I am not seeing it show up.

I followed the directions given in this post: [RHEL 6 - how to install 'GLIBC_2.14' or 'GLIBC_2.15'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32316707/rhel-6-how-to-install-glibc-2-14-or-glibc-2-15)

Any ideas, I am clueless and frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install glibc 2.14 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.  It will break the system and make it unsupportable.

You will have obtain the software you want to run in a version that was built for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6, or upgrade to Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.